# What WebGrid does Microsoft use in their website?

Tags: asp.net

I just wonder what asp.net datagrid does Microsoft use in their website? For example, "Visual Studio 2010 Team web Access" site. It has frozen columns and re-order columns functions. Is it a third party grid or it is based on asp.net datagrid?

The grid works in both IE and safari.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS bought the company that wrote Team Web Access.  My guess is that its not a 3rd party control, but something they've written themselves with the help of the Ajax toolkit:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HoverMenu/HoverMenu.aspx

I think its a really well designed site, but if you look closely a lot of it is clever use of css.  They have just spent a long time on designing the interface.